# Is it possible to use both annotations and hbm.xml files in the same project in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Does one necessarily have to make a strict choice between using annotations and hibernate configuration files, or is it possible to use both ways at the same time in the same project?

We have a large project done with Hibernate 3.2.5 and POJOs configured with `.hbm.xml` files. The project uses Hibernate `SessionManager` Factory and not JTA-based `EntityManager` factory.

There are over a hundred POJOs configured that way and the original developer team is reluctant to switch to annotations.

Meanwhile we need to extend the project with more POJOs which we are willing to configure with Hibernate annotations and want to stay with Hibernate - if possible - and not switch to JPA.

Is it possible to use a combination of `.hbm.xml` config files for some POJOs and annotations for others at the same time?

Comment: Given the bugginess of tools such as NetBeans and in many cases even Eclipse, I often get errors even when I code and configure things right. So for something even many Java experts say "dunno, never tried", I wouldn't waste my time trial-error without being sure if it is my error, or the IDE, or just because it can't simply be done in Java / Hibernate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manu has given the answer but if you are going to switch to annotations and you want to convert those hbm.xml to annotations. Please go on. You can use the tools that will generate the pojo classes with annotations from existing tables. Even using those tools, You dont have to change the other code just generate the pojos like before. i.e. dont change property names. I have worked on same kinda project and I used Ant script for that.

Answer (score 15):

**Yes you can.** The [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html#setup-configuration) says

> Note that you can mix the legacy hbm.xml use and the annotation approach. The resource element can be either an hbm file or an EJB3 XML deployment descriptor.

There are a few check point though:

> You can however not declare a class several times (whether annotated or through hbm.xml). You cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity hierarchy either.

You can find some more information [here](http://community.jboss.org/thread/1914).

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is great but with actual code example it'll be better. I've tried ManuPK ref and this's how it's work. 

My actual ref is here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html#setup-configuration

```
//typical way to use cfg.xml
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
SessionFactory f = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session s = f.openSession();
s.persist(new EntityObj());

//to use both annotation & cfg.xml mappings, use AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration
AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
SessionFactory f = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session s = f.openSession();
s.persist(new EntityObj());
```

AnnotationConfiguration will read the cfg.xml as usual to parse both <mapping resource="your_entity.hbm.xml"/> and <mapping class="my.entity.objclass"/>

**Disclaimer**: I tried using the old Hibernate ver 3.2.1 and it's running fine.