# Java Hibernate Named query not known

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

Hi I am trying to use anotation to do named query. The line that caused  Named query not known is:

```
HibernateUtil.openSession().getNamedQuery(
                    "getWorkById")
```

Here is all the code about my named query. Actually I also tried to do so in mapping files, but I also got error and don't know what error is because it just reported internal failure. Any help about how to fix the error? Also, what is a better practice to do named query? Thanks!

WorkModel:

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getWorkById", query = "from myday.work w where w.id = :id")
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "myday.work")
public class WorkModel {
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

WorkModel hbm xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.WorkModel" table="myday.work">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate cfg xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://XXX:3306</property>
        // username, pwd setting...

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="model.WorkModel"/>
        <mapping resource="model/WorkModel.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Why are you using both the xml and annotations for mapping? Try removing the xml mapping. Also look this answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8313395/738746.

Comment: I meant I have tried two differnet ways

Comment: Did you try by removing `<mapping resource="model/WorkModel.hbm.xml"/>` from your hibernate config file? Keep only `<mapping class="model.WorkModel"/>`.

Comment: I think Gurung said the point, the xml config overrides the annotation config.

Comment: thanks Gurung, that helps. but now I got new errors: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getWorkById
 Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError